# element unvisible until developer console opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've got a website where some LayerSlider elements stay invisible until

- the window is resized
- I disable the Bookmarks bar in Chrome (whaaat ?)
- I switch on Chrome debugger tools

The issue also appears in Firefox and Safari on OS X (all on the newest versions).

I have no idea what that could be. To me it looks like some OS render issue.

I am looking for a workaround.

How can I trigger some kind of repaint after pageload that will unhide those elements? (same thing that happens when I open the dev console for instance)

I tried `jQuery(document.body).hide().show();` but that doesn't work.

There is bit more info to it:

The image is hidden because it is scaled to zero height and with after the initial load

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/example.png" class="ls-bg" alt="alpha_video" style="padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin-left: 765.5px; margin-top: 299px;">
```

After the resize of the window the image size of that element suddenly changes (some kind of on the fly HTML manipulation)

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/example.png" class="ls-bg" alt="alpha_video" style="padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 1508px; height: 612.625px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -11.8125px;">
```

How is such a resize being done?
Why doesn't it happen after the initial load?
How can I trigger it?

Comment: I think anyone who wants to help you is going to need more information. Maybe some `CSS` and `HTML`?

Comment: Jefré N: I added the <img> element code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Michael Sparks I created this solution. It can be placed anywhere in the header, body or footer. It will be executed after the entire page has loaded to make sure that all elements get fixed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( window ).load(function(){
    jQuery( window ).trigger( 'resize' );
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I trigger some kind of repaint after pageload that will unhide
>   those elements?

```
function afterload(callback) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    callback();
  } else {
    jQuery(window).on('load', callback);
  }
}

afterload(function () {
  jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Excellent! That works. Michael Sparks. Do you also know why that <img> element doesn't get the right height and with after the first pageload?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: I will use this code though. It waits until the entire page has loaded and then applies your function: `jQuery( window ).load(jQuery(window).trigger('resize'));`

Comment: that works so long as you aren't executing it after the page has already loaded :)

Comment: N'ah. Wrong with my first attempt. But this one works after page load: `jQuery( window ).load(function(){
 jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
});`

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've had luck with:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

and/or in older IE:

```
hasLayout: true;
```

If you share some more info might be able to pinpoint it down a bit more.